# Can you map a network drive to a SSRS report directory?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We are working at getting our versioning control product to automatically push our SSRS reports to the Test (and then production) SSRS environment. When we promote changes from our development to our QA directory in the versioning control application (Surround SCM),  we would like for it to also publish the report to SSRS. (This is the workflow we use for our web applications, and if possible I would like to be consistent).

Now, the directories in SSRS are not "real" directories, at least not as far as I can tell. But is there any way to map a network drive to one of these report directories? And if we do this, and Surround SCM can write changes to that directory, would they then be saved to SSRS?

Sorry in advance if this is a really esoteric question, or if I am missing a really obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't directly map SSRS folders to a Windows filesystem. I haven't found a way to make what you describe as easy as I think it should be.

The easiest way to automate the deployment of reports uses of the [rs.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256617%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) utility. This can execute scripts to deploy or update reports.

Alternatively, you could use the SSRS web services to deploy the reports from .NET code.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the quick reply...I was afraid this was the case.